# Passing Different Parameter for Same File using URL Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have user.php file and I m passing two parameters with it using URL Rewrite
but I m unable to use this rule as whichever rule is written first only gets executed and not the second one in case of my rule for `userID` rule doesn't work but work for `webName`. Any solution will be very much helpful to me.Thank you

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?webName=$1     [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?userID=$1    [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Because your regural expression is same in each line :)))

Comment: What criteria decides whether to use `webname=` or `userId=` ?

Comment: Do you want to execute `user.php` twice for a request, or do you have two different request that have to be redirected differently?

Comment: @Thakkie yeah I want to execute user.php twice based on parameters

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Thakkie if db user dont have webName it will take userID for respective user

Comment: So you do not want to execute user.php twice. What you want is when there is a userId use the first rule, but when there is not then use the second?

Comment: @Thakkie Hmm yes something like that

Comment: So then Peters answer is correct.

Comment: @Thakkie Yes It works now for me.Thanks to you as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a difference between two regural expression:

If you would like to catch user ID you should filter for only numbers: `\d`

Then if there is another chars in url not only numbers you can match for anything except kslash: `[^/]`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)$ user.php?userID=$1     [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ user.php?webName=$1    [L,QSA]
```

Comment: and what is the diffrence between this two rules (those written in round bracket)

Comment: Please take your time read something about regular expressions, then you will see the difference :) '\d' matches only numbers '[^/]' matches everything except /

Comment: Hmm yeah thank you your rule worked for me but before using my rule I tried dissimilar expression for both rule still it was not working

Comment: I don't understand what you need :)) Now is it works or not?